# Using VBA on word, how do I change fields on header?

Tags: vba, ms-word, reference

I'm working on a template doc that I can copy to different folders. When I open the doc I want it to find a excel file with name "Mod127*.xlsx" on the same folder and update the source path of all fields to that Excel file.

I wrote this code for that effect, and it works, with the exception of a field located in the header of the document

```
Dim fieldCount As Integer, x As Long
With ActiveDocument
    ficheiro = Dir(.Path & "\Mod127*")
    If ficheiro = "" Then
        MsgBox "Model 127 not found in folder"
    Else
        fieldCount = .Fields.Count
        For x = 1 To fieldCount
            With .Fields(x)
                If .Type = 56 Then ' Type 56 is an excel link
                    .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ficheiro
                    .Update
                    .LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = False
                    DoEvents
                End If
            End With
        Next x
    End If
End With
```

Any idea on how to reach that headers field?

I also tried cross referencing one of the fields to the heading, but I get a "reference not found" after the code runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers and footers are child objects of the `Section`. Dependent on the page layout of the section there may be up to 3 headers and footers, so you will need to know which one(s) to update. The code below should get you started.

```
        With .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields(1)
                .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ficheiro
                .Update
                .LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = False
                DoEvents
        End With
```

Comment: Thank you, it's all I needed to know, added another loop to go through all sections and now everything updates properly